# How to retrieve status from different individual and set it as completed if all status are completed

Tags: php, sql

In this system, there are three user: admin, person in-charge & user

Flow of the system:

- admin choose MULTIPLE(max 3) person in-charge for one complain
- each person in-charge will update their own status
- user will view main status

Problem:

how to update main status whereby:

- if all status = 'Completed' then main status = 'Completed'
- if any status = 'Incomplete' then main status = 'Incomplete'

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question accordingly. You need to provide us with your attempt, example data, expected results and what results you're currently getting.

Comment: I dont know where to start. Im a beginner

Comment: Start by reading the link I posted and update your question accordingly. The question is currently a bit too unspecific and broad.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When a 'person-in-charge' update his status as complete, you need to do the check, whether the status for this complaint id is still 'incomplete'. If no, you can update the complaint status as 'Completed'.

```
MainComplaint Table
ID | Details | Status     |
1  | Xxxxxx  | Incomplete |

PersonAssign Table
CompaintID | PersonID | Status     |
1         | 1        | Incomplete |
1         | 2        | Incomplete |
1         | 3        | Incomplete |
```

Whenever an assigned person updates, there will be status check with complaintID.

```
$sql = "UPDATE PersonAssign SET status = 'Completed' 
            WHERE ComplaintID = 1 and PersonID = $logged_user_id";

$sqlCheck = "SELECT status FROM PersonAssign WHERE ComplaintID = 1 and status = 'Incomplete'";
if(number of rows == 0) {
    //means there is no incomplete status
    UPDATE the MainComplain table
}
```

Comment: May I know why this downvote for?